# How to show variable inside function in vue3 template

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How can I display the variable inside template? I use Nuxtjs version 3.2.

I set return but its not show in the template

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p> Countdown:  {{ `${days}` }} {{  minutes }} {{ seconds }} </p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
        const countDownDate = new Date("Apr 28, 2023 16:37:52").getTime();


const myfunc = setInterval(function() {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    var timeleft = countDownDate - now;
    
    let days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    return { days , hours , minutes , seconds}
}, 1000)
   
</script>
```

---

With the watchEffect working.

```
<template>
<div>
  <p>Countdown: {{ `${days}` }} {{ hours }} {{ minutes }} {{ seconds }} </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';

export default {
setup() {
  const countDownDate = new Date('Apr 28, 2023 16:37:52').getTime();
  const days = ref(0);
  const hours = ref(0);
  const minutes = ref(0);
  const seconds = ref(0);

  watchEffect(() => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const timeleft = countDownDate - now;

    days.value = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    hours.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 
 60));
    minutes.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    seconds.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  });

  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
  },
 };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Vue's reactivity](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

Define your variables with `ref()`

```
const days = ref(0);
```

And set them in your function using `.value`:

```
days.value = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

### Here is the Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const countDownDate = new Date("Apr 28, 2023 16:37:52").getTime();

const App = {
  setup() {    

    const days = ref(0);
    const hours = ref(0);
    const minutes = ref(0);
    const seconds = ref(0);

    const myfunc = setInterval(function() {
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      var timeleft = countDownDate - now;

      days.value = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      hours.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      minutes.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      seconds.value = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      
    }, 1000)
  
    return { days, hours, minutes, seconds }
  }
  
}
const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.5; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <b>Countdown:</b><br/>
  <p>  Days {{ days }}, Hours {{ hours }}, Minutes: {{  minutes }}, Seconds: {{ seconds }} </p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

---

`<script setup>` version [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: not working, even with ref() the time is not show in the template. 
This is a components and I need to use inside a template page.

Comment: @Federico, did you write your methods inside `<script setup>`?

Comment: Yes is inside <script setup>. 
I got those warning :  

Property "days" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.                          
[Vue warn]: Property "minutes" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.             
[Vue warn]: Property "seconds" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

Comment: @Federico, I added a `<script setup>` version of it, at the end of the answer. I've also made slight improvements to it. But, in essence, it's the same thing.

Comment: @tao I like your improvements. Good work!